# Listen for click / hover on individual axis labels

Tags: anychart

I'm looking for a way to change the value (or format) for an individual series label when hovering it in anycharts.

Currently I'm only able to access the entire axis and I can find no getter method for individual labels so as to attach a listener.

```
xAxis.labels().listen('mouseOver', function(e) {
    console.log(this, e.target);
});
```

This jsfiddle is as far as I got (see console log), this as well as the event.target reference the entire axis but not the label:

https://jsfiddle.net/robstarbuck/pbhd4b7L/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there was a little bug with cache and format() function, our dev team made the fix, so please check the working sample:

```
var labelIndex = e.labelIndex;
var label = this.getLabel(labelIndex);
var value = xAxis.scale().ticks().get()[labelIndex];
label.format(value * 2);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pbhd4b7L/13/ – it also shows how to work with tick values:

Currently it takes the js from branch, but this fix will be included in the upcoming release – 7.14.0 version (ETA: May 2017)

Answer (score 1):

Our API is a little bit complicated here, but we're working hard to improve it. Does this what you're looking for?

```
    var labelIndex = e.labelIndex;
    var label = this.getLabel(labelIndex);
    label.fontColor('red');
    label.draw();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pbhd4b7L/10/

Comment: so close! How could I then `format` the label to show a different value, it would need to reference the current value which I also can't access.

Comment: Put a different way, is there a way to get the value of the variable `label` in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in the 7.14.0 release, use this code:

```
  xAxis.labels().listen('mouseOver', function(e) {
    var labelIndex = e.labelIndex;
    var label = this.getLabel(labelIndex);
    var value = xAxis.scale().ticks().get()[labelIndex];
    label.format(value * 2);
    label.fontColor('red');
    label.draw();
  });
```

with the latest version: https://jsfiddle.net/2t08ahkg/3/